# show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0^{+}}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}a_{i}^{t}]^{1/t}$ is the geometric mean of $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$ be any n positive real numbers. show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow0^{+}}[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{t}]^{1/t}$ is the geometric mean of  $a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n}$

Comment: First use $a^b=e^{bln(a)}$, put the limit inside exponential and use L hôpital rule.